# How to create a calendar table following ISO 8601 in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a table that will look like this in PostgresSQL and I've already tried different codes but none of them seem to work on PgAdmin. (I also wanted the table to have multiple years, not only 2021).

[image: 1]

Comment: you have to provide sample data , also avoid pasting screenshots

Comment: Why is the line with id = 7 red?

Comment: The red line was just an example used to explain a production order.

Comment: PostgreSQL like all databases (except SQLite) has multiple date types. There's no reason at all to store dates as strings, so talking about `a calendar table following ISO 8601` doesn't explain anything. Besides, a Calendar table is something very specific - a table containing a row for every date for the next eg 50 years, along with any extra columns needed for reporting, eg year, month, day of month, day of week, week number, quarter, month name etc

Comment: What you posted isn't a calendar table. If anything, it looks like an Excel screenshot. `Start` and `End` look like date values whose cell style is `dd/mm/yy` and `Friday` like a calculated column whose style is `dd-mmm`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i wanted to create a calendar table to store in my Data Base so that I could use it in Lazarus App. The intention was making the interface show in what week of the plan we were and respective details of that week.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes! the screenshot is from excel but I wanted to create one with those columns in PgAdmin

Comment: @JMAido so what do you want to create? That screenshot doesn't help *at all*. PostgreSQL has proper date types, you don't need strings. If you want to store dates, just use `date` for the three columns

Comment: @JMAido If the answer solved your problem then accept it. This helps future questioners that may have the same issue, and a token reward for the answerer's time. Please do not leave a successfully answered question open.

Comment: @Belayer thank you for bringing my attention to it. As I said I'm new here and really don't know the dynamics of stackoverflow. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` to generate an output like that (which isn't really a "calendar table" as what is commonly understood by that term):

```
select row_number() over (order by t.week_start) as id, 
       extract(isoyear from t.week_start) as year, 
       extract(week from t.week_start) as nr,
       t.week_start::date as "start", 
       (t.week_start + interval '1 week')::date - 1 as "end",
       (t.week_start + interval '1 week')::date - 3 as friday
from generate_series(to_date('2021-04', 'iyyy-iw'), 
                     to_date('2021-04', 'iyyy-iw') + interval '11 week', 
                     interval '1 week') as t(week_start)
```

You can adjust the start and end dates to your liking. This one uses your example which starts in week 4 of 2021 for 11 weeks.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e7b85598cf092b2a05ae1cf1c953d81d)

---

> I wanted to create a calendar table to store in my Data Base so that I could use it in Lazarus App.

As you can see in my example, there is no need to create such a table in the database - at least not if it's just for display purposes.

To create  proper calendar table, you wouldn't actually store the derived information like week number of week start or end date in the table.

If it's really about weeks, *you* could do something like this:

```
create table week_table 
(
  id integer primary key, 
  week_start date not null
);

-- insert all weeks for 2021
insert into week_table
select row_number() over (order by t.week_start) as id, 
       t.week_start::date
from generate_series(to_date('2021-01', 'iyyy-iw'), 
                     to_date('2021-01', 'iyyy-iw') + interval '1 year', 
                     interval '1 week') as t(week_start);
```

Then use that table to generate the output you want.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. Im a newbie in PostGres and also a newbie in StackOverflow. Sorry if my question wasnt straightforward for you guys.

Comment: @JMAido: see my edit on how to generate a table that contains one row per week. Btw: the database is called PostgreSQL or just Post**g**res  - no capital G in the name